# Got "No preprocessor test for "Intel"" when configure a project with CMake

Tags: cmake, mingw, mingw-w64

I have a problem when cmake launch first program test.
In fact I launch this command (docker container from mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1809-AMD64) :

```
cmake.exe -B Build_Windows -DTarget=Windows -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug  -G "Ninja" -DCodeCoverage=OFF -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=C:/workdir/compiler/mingw-w64-7.3.0/bin/gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=C:/workdir/compiler/mingw-w64-7.3.0/bin/g++.exe -S .
```

I have this result :

```
CMake Error at C:/workdir/compiler/cmake-3.14.0-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/cmakecompileriddetection.cmake:111 (message):

  No preprocessor test for "Intel"

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/workdir/compiler/cmake-3.14.0-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/cmakedeterminecompilerid.cmake:151 (compiler_id_detection)

  C:/workdir/compiler/cmake-3.14.0-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/cmakedeterminecompilerid.cmake:170 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_WRITE)

  C:/workdir/compiler/cmake-3.14.0-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/cmakedeterminecompilerid.cmake:31 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)

  C:/workdir/compiler/cmake-3.14.0-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/cmakedetermineccompiler.cmake:113 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)
```

When open `CMakeErrorLog.txt`:

```
The target system is: Windows -  - 
The host system is: Windows - 10.0.17763 - AMD64
```

I don't understand why, all path compilers are ok.

Comment: Have you checked what is in `C:/workdir/compiler/cmake-3.14.0-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/cmakecompileriddetection.cmake` on line 111 that causes this messages?
Also note that MinGW-w64 GCC 7.3.0 is very old, and CMake 3.14 also a few years old. Have you tried with newer versions? You can get a standalone build of MinGW-w64 GCC 11.2.0 from https://winlibs.com/ and CMake 3.22.1 from https://cmake.org/download/

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer,
Yes, I know my cmake and mingw are very old but my project can't updated now. 
But I can compile this project on another computer. 

On line 111 I have this :
    foreach(Id ${ordered_compilers})
      if (NOT _compiler_id_pp_test_${Id})
        message(FATAL_ERROR "No preprocessor test for \"${Id}\"")

Comment: Can you try to add `C:/workdir/compiler/mingw-w64-7.3.0/bin` to the `PATH` environment variable (in Command Prompt: `SET PATH=C:\workdir\compiler\mingw-w64-7.3.0\bin;$PATH`) and the use `-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++` instead?

Comment: I have same result,
 No preprocessor test for "Intel"

Comment: I have updagred cmake I have this error now :
Checking whether the C compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files

Comment: Are you cross compiling? If not you can leave out `-DTarget=Windows`

Comment: I have resolved my problem to change window version container. This problem is due to windows docker image .